# How to apply percentage-based values to a child-element?

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid header-layout that's based nearly solely on percentage values (width, padding, margin) like that

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>
            <h4>Foo2</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Underfoo</li>
                <li>Underfoo2</li>
                <li><img src="superimage.jpg"/></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Foo3</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

and the styling of these like that

```
header{
width:100%;
}
header ul{
width:100%;
}

header ul li{
width:33.3%
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Alright til here. But if I then want to apply percentage-based values to the nested elements dependent on their parent element, this doesn't work. So if I do something that:

```
header ul li ul li{
width:33.33%
padding:0 15%;
}
```

I get elements that are 33.3% wide as the header-container NOT as the parental li-container, same with padding. So of course I could now make 33.3/3 = 11.1% width and that would be the result I want, but it seems to be quite odd. What do I do wrong there?

Thanks

Comment: try add `position:relative;` to your `header ul li`

Comment: Your example code has quite some errors currently. Please fix those before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write with child selector as this

```
 header > ul > li{

 header > ul > li ul li{
```

Remember to apply border-box to all elements because you are using padding

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position:relative;` to the parent element if you want children to adopt the size of the parent.
here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smyd640u/)